# Database in Netbeans onclick button

Tags: java, netbeans

I am following this tutorial about making a database in Netbeans:
http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/database_scrolling_buttons.html
I have a button Next on my JPanel, which must call this method:

```java
private void btnNextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    try {
        String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employees";
        String uName = "bjorn";
        String uPass= "";
        conN = DriverManager.getConnection( host, uName, uPass );
        stmtN = conN.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM App.Workers";
        rsN = stmtN.executeQuery( SQL );

        if ( rsN.next( ) ) {
            int id_col = rsN.getInt("ID");
            String id = Integer.toString(id_col);
            String first_name = rsN.getString("First_Name");
            String last_name = rsN.getString("Last_Name");
            String job = rsN.getString("Job_Title");

            textID.setText(id);
            textFirstName.setText(first_name);
            textLastName.setText(last_name);
            textJobTitle.setText(job);
        }
        else {
            rsN.previous( );
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Workers.this, "End of File");
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException err) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Workers.this, err.getMessage());
    }        // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

This method must show the next entry of the database on the JPanel, but I can't get it working. Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Although I am almost sure you already saw this site: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/java-db.html it is another tutorial on derby databases with netbeans. But I actually wanted to asked if you checked your database and the queries you are using with different means? For example Netbeans can directly establish a connection with your database and you can test your queries in a simple way, to make sure that there are no syntax errors in your queries or the db uri.

Comment: I don't think the query is wrong, because when I use rsN.last() instead of rsN.next(), the last entry of the database is shown.

Comment: In Netbeans, click on *Window* > *Services* and right click the category *databases*. There you can add a *new connection*. If you follow the steps, netbeans will guide you through everything until it can establish a connection to your database and show you the database content (in tables). Test your sql statements directly in the sql editor of netbeans … if they work you know that your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: In that case try using `rsN.next()` one time before reading the data. It means the db cursor needs to point at the "first" entry.

Comment: I have one statement rs.next() already in a method DoConnect, as shown in the tutorial. But when I click the Next-button, the Jpanel must show the next entry, so I think rsN.next() must be the condition of the if-statement. But why is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
      PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM  App.Workers",ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

    if(rs.next())
       {
      int id_col = rsN.getInt("ID");
        String id = Integer.toString(id_col);
        String first_name = rsN.getString("First_Name");
        String last_name = rsN.getString("Last_Name");
        String job = rsN.getString("Job_Title");

        textID.setText(id);
        textFirstName.setText(first_name);
        textLastName.setText(last_name);
        textJobTitle.setText(job);  

 }
   else
 {
   rs.beforeFirst();
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Workers.this, "End of File");
  }
```

Try This..

Comment: Your code is causing the panel to jump to the first record again. But how can I let it jump to the next record? And where is your 'conn' coming from?

Comment: you can declare this statement is a static variable.. and remove the `rs.beforeFirst();` Then try this..

Comment: When I declare    public static Connection con = null; in my class Workers, the program still not works.

Answer (score 0):

Declare This into Main in `Static Resultset rsN;` and following database Connection

```
try 
  {
    String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employees";
    String uName = "bjorn";
    String uPass= "";
    conN = DriverManager.getConnection( host, uName, uPass );
    stmtN = conN.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,  ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    String SQL = "SELECT * FROM App.Workers";
   Static Resultset rsN = stmtN.executeQuery( SQL );
 }
catch (SQLException err) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Workers.this, err.getMessage());
}        // TODO add your handling code here:
```

in the button action performed You can use this..

```
  private void btnNextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)               {                                        

    try
    {
    if ( rsN.next( ) ) {
        int id_col = rsN.getInt("ID");
        String id = Integer.toString(id_col);
        String first_name = rsN.getString("First_Name");
        String last_name = rsN.getString("Last_Name");
        String job = rsN.getString("Job_Title");

        textID.setText(id);
        textFirstName.setText(first_name);
        textLastName.setText(last_name);
        textJobTitle.setText(job);
    }
    else {
        rsN.previous( );
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Workers.this, "End of File");
    }
}
catch (SQLException err) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Workers.this, err.getMessage());
}        // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

It's working try this..